# download large file from url using node js

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I want to donwload large file from my simple http server. I am using node-webkit application.
and simple http.get method to download file but it is not downloading large files from server.
here is code i have written.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
var request = http.get("http://something.zip", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

This code is working fine when I download file from my local server. But when I provide url of file hosted on server then it is not working.
My application downloading zip file from server in both cases but while downloading file from internet after 5-10%, connection closes.

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a protocol or path on your http request?

Comment: I hv provided complete url of zip instead of "something.zip". its working when I download file from local, but its not working when I download file from internet

Comment: Then, you need to figure out and share more about what is different in the case that works and the case that doesn't work.  You've now edited your answer into `http://something.zip` which I assume you know is not a valid URL unless `something.zip` is the domain name.

Comment: "http://something.zip" is only to show. my application downloading zip file from server in both cases but while downloading file from internet after 5-10%, connection closes.

Comment: Then, add that information to your question.  How do you expect us to know the answer to a situation that only occurs in certain configurations if you don't give us all the information and tell us what steps you've taken to troubleshoot the situation?